# In Excel for web, when using functions that output an array (SUMIF, UNIQUE) how can I filter `0` values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel for web, I use certain functions like UNIQUE and SUMIF over large ranges. Often times these ranges contain blank values, and UNIQUE will output a `0`, and SUMIF too. How can I filter these?

I've tried using the FILTER function, but it doesn't seem like that's meant for arrays.

With the following example I get the values that I want, followed by a long list of zeros. Is there any way I can prevent that?

```
=SUMIF(Transactions!$J$3:$J$1000, $A$2:$A$1000, Transactions!$F$3:$F$1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$A$2:$A$1000` with `FILTER($A$2:$A$1000,$A$2:$A$1000<>"")`

```
=SUMIF(Transactions!$J$3:$J$1000, FILTER($A$2:$A$1000,$A$2:$A$1000<>""), Transactions!$F$3:$F$1000)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. So filter the column first, and then feed it into SUMIF and UNIQUE instead of doing the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

For example data in column **A**, pick a cell and enter:

```
=FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A))
```

the spill-down will eliminate the blanks.

[image]